# Getting coordinates and place names with Twython streaming

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, coordinates, twython

For my research I'm trying to get the coordinates or placenames from tweets related to certain keywords. I have little programming experience and even less so in Python, but I'm trying :). I'm using Twython for the streaming of the tweets. Im able to get the tweets, tweetid and usernames but not the place coordinates or place names.

What I've got so far is the standard streaming lines from Twython with some little modifications:

```
APP_KEY = '***'
APP_SECRET = '***'
OAUTH_TOKEN = '***'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = '***'

from pprint import pprint
from twython import TwythonStreamer

class MyStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
    def on_success(self, data):
        if 'text' in data:
            print data['text'].encode('utf-8')

        if 'id_str' in data:
            print 'Tweetid: '+ data['id_str'].encode('utf-8')

        if 'user' in data:
            print 'Username:  '+ data['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')

        print data['coordinates']['coordinates']

        print    
        print '-----------------------------------------------'
        print

    def on_error(self, status_code, data):
        print status_code
        self.disconnect()

stream = MyStreamer(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

stream.statuses.filter(track='ajax')
```

The error I get is: 
"print data['coordinates']['coordinates']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'"

Now I can see that you probably cant use the same method to call the coordinates? But thats where my programming knowledge ends, sadly enough :). The solution is probably easy but couldnt find it anywhere!

Thanks alot in advance!

Kind regards,

Jim

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets

Coordinates are nullable, which means they are not necessarily present.
You can test for their presence just as you did with the other fields :

```
if 'coordinates' in data:
    ...
```